# Redis scan family commands via laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I am new to using Laravel and Redis together. I'm trying to run the Redis command `zscan`:

```
$redis = Redis::connection();
$redis->zscan('zset', 0, 'mor*'));
```

but when I do, I get the message:

```
'zscan' is not a registered Redis command
```

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Are you running Redis >2.8.0? `zscan` wasn't available before 2.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 4 uses the Predis Redis driver (look at the composer.json file to check that). The Zscan command was added to Predis 0.8.5.

Use

```
composer show -i
```

To check the installed version, and ensure the Predis installed version is at least 0.8.5.

Comment: i just check it. v0.8.5